# Use ExceptionMapper to log CLIENT_ERRORs

Tags: java, exception, jax-rs, dropwizard, exceptionmapper

I am working on an application which uses Dropwizard, which has this implementation of ExceptionMapper: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-jersey/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/jersey/errors/LoggingExceptionMapper.java

Problem with this implementation is that even though this catches both 4** and 5** errors, it only logs 5** errors.

I need to implement ExceptionMapper such that LoggingExceptionMapper is not used at all and my CustomExceptionMapper logs both CLIENT_ERRORs and SERVER_ERRORs.

I am wondering how would my application know that it needs to use CustomExceptionMapper instead of the Dropwizard class?

Also would it suffice to add CLIENT_ERROR to if condition, to log out all errors?

```
@Override
public Response toResponse(E exception) {
    // If we're dealing with a web exception, we can service certain types of request (like
    // redirection or server errors) better and also propagate properties of the inner response.
    if (exception instanceof WebApplicationException) {
        final Response response = ((WebApplicationException) exception).getResponse();
        Response.Status.Family family = response.getStatusInfo().getFamily();
        if (family.equals(Response.Status.Family.REDIRECTION)) {
            return response;
        }
        if (family.equals(Response.Status.Family.SERVER_ERROR) || family.equals(Response.Status.Family.CLIENT_ERROR) {
            logException(exception);
        }

        return Response.fromResponse(response)
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .entity(new ErrorMessage(response.getStatus(), exception.getLocalizedMessage()))
                .build();
    }
```

Or would there be a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JAX-RS spec](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/) about ExceptionMapper:

> When choosing an exception mapping provider to map an exception, an
>   implementation MUST use the provider whose generic type is the nearest
>   superclass of the exception.

**How would my application know that it needs to use CustomExceptionMapper instead of the Dropwizard class?**

You can throw a custom exception from your application and create an ExceptionMapper for that specific exception.

**Would it suffice to add CLIENT_ERROR to if condition, to log out all errors?**

Yes, 4xx and 5xx family has all the error responses.